# Accessing AWS EC2 instance with SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I started to play with AWS EC2 for the first time and as usual with AWS, nothing is simple. I am reading this document, because I can't SSH to my instance:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

At one point it reads:

2. In the navigation pane, choose Security Groups. Select one of the security groups associated with your instance.
3. In the details pane, on the Inbound tab, choose Edit. In the dialog, choose Add Rule, and then choose SSH from the Type list.

The problem is when I choose one security group, I see nothing but a white page.

Same, if I select Inbound rules, within Security Groups, I don' see any detail pane or Edit button where I could try something.

What can I be doing wrong?

In case this may be useful there are only 2 security groups
MongoDB-MongoDBServersSecurityGroup-123..ABC, MongoDB-MongoDBServerSecurityGroup-678..XYS

Here is a screen shot of what I see it I choose one security group.

[image: Console][1]]

When I select Inbound rules, within Security Groups, this is what I see.

[image: Security Group]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: I just edited the POST.

Comment: You may just need to scroll up on the right side. If that doesn't help, then try an incognito window.

Comment: Can you try clearing all your cookies. Looks like its broken in the AWS interface

Comment: @Michel Try clearing the browser cache, too

Comment: There is nothing to scroll on the right. I tried clearing the cache and cookies, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: That is really weird.  Are you sure your account has the proper privileges to access the security groups?  (Although, if it didn't, you should see a clear error stating that.)  What platform are you on?  What browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: I am the only user, I don't see why it wouldn't have those privileges.

Comment: I may well be in a particular case without knowing it. I made a previous test with an EC2 instance a few hours before and there I had an SSH access.

Comment: This instance of EC2 has been created using this document:
https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/mongodb/
This may explain something. But of course I am not sure of that.

Comment: Try disabling the 'New EC2 Experience' (see top-left of page) and revert to the old UI. This sounds like a problem either with your browser or, less likely, its compatibility with the new UI.